# Edges are not visible in Blender with Wireframe

Tags: wireframe

Edges are not visible in Blender with Wireframe. wireframe behaves strangely.

In the first two screenshots, I show that I can't see the object because of the references

https://ibb.co/Pm1WX82
https://ibb.co/F5TFvXD

In the same screenshots, I show that the edges are not visible
https://ibb.co/ygtWXGT
https://ibb.co/bH3b2mk

Comment: hello, maybe a problem of driver? What does it give if you switch to a previous one?

Comment: hello, the older version is not supported on my PC

Comment: maybe try Render panel > Performance > High-Quality Normals?

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please edit your post to include the screenshot directly in the post instead of using links, which can expire and make your post useless.

Comment: Hello, maybe Overlays > [Geometry](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.4/editors/3dview/display/overlays.html#geometry) > Opacity.

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.